# Stackoverflow at Arrays.asList(str.split(",")) -> due to wrong recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking

**EDIT :** The commaString operation wasn't the problem. It was my fault. See below.

*I wrote a method to convert a comma String to an String List. 
But i got a stackoverflow in this method.*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.ArrayList.subList(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at de.dhbw.horb.routePlanner.SupportMethods.commaStrToStrList(SupportMethods.java:82)

public static List<String> commaStrToStrList(String commaStr) {
    if (commaStr == null)
        return null;
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(commaStr.split(",")));
}
```

*So why is this happening? Is my commaStr to big? If yes, what else can use for this?*

The method doNextNode(id) is an recursion.:
https://github.com/Spenhouet/RoutenplanerProjekt/blob/master/Routenplaner/main/de/dhbw/horb/routePlanner/parser/JDomGraphDataCreator.java

**EDIT :**

The problem was due to a missing clause in my recursion method. So the recursion got very deep. At first i pushed my max stack size to 3GB (-Xss3g) but it ended off in an out of memory exception. :/

Then i thought of if it could be possible that my recursion starts over at one point and is doing the same thing again and again. Therefor i've added a map that holds every visited node (id) with removing the nodes for failed recusions (backtracking).

Now it works like a charm.
**Thanks to Marco13** for pointing out that eventually my recursion is getting to deep.

Comment: Why do you put it into a new ArrayList, if your return type is List? Couldn't you just return the `Arrays.asList` ?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin  Something like the following: "first,second,third,fourth"

Comment: @besnep thats it?? nothing more?? can you post the whole string?

Comment: @MightyPork I assume OP would want to manipulate this List later but you can't add or remove elements to list which would be result of `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No, sorry that was just an example because i thought you didn't understand what a comma String is. My comma String holds a lot of ids (alot!!).

Comment: @besnep if it is more than the Integer.MAX then that is the overflow

Comment: It must be some extremely huge list to cause stack overflow, it works fine for me. Perhaps not the greatest idea to build such string in the first place?

Comment: Let's say i need it as comma string. Is there a other way to convert it to an string list?

Comment: Is this method called as the last method of deep recursive calls? You should probably show us more of the stack trace - or did you omit it because it only contained the same line thousands of times? ;-)

Comment: @Marco13 I've linked my project (git) in the post. The method is a recursion. But i thought i made all exit possibilities.

Comment: A StackOverflowError does not *necessarily* mean that the recursion is infinite. It only means that the recursion is too deep. A recursion depth of 100000 will cause an SOE, even if it is limited to this depth. A test case where the problem can be reproduced (preferably as a single(!) copy+pastable code block here!) would be helpful. Otherwise: **IF** the recursion depth is limited, you can just try starting with `java -Xss2m YourApplication` to increase the stack size to 2MB and see whether this is enough in your case.

Comment: @Marco13 You are right! My recursion had a missing exit clause (doing something again...). I've edited the total question above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string is so big that `String.split()` breaks on it, you have the following options:

1. Try [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), <strike>it's unlikely to be much better but it's worth a go</strike>. Update: I checked the source code of this and it looks pretty simple and memory-efficient, equivalent with option 3.
2. Use a raw regex [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and build your list manually.
3. Do all the parsing manually: iterate over the characters and if you hit a comma, create a string with the characters between the last comma and the current one and add it to the list.

If you still run out of memory, a more sophisticated approach is required, probably involving writing the string into a file and reading it back in smaller chunks.

Comment: Mh it looks like i will have to think about a other solution.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.String.indexOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.scanToken(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
 ...

Comment: Now this is weird because `StringTokenizer` definitely isn't using recursion, call stack depth won't depend on the length of the string scanned. Are you sure there isn't a runaway recursion in the calling code somewhere? Can you show a few more lines from the stack trace?

Comment: @biziclop As far as I can see, it's not even clear whether there is some recursion involved in the *original* program. When the posted method is at the "bottom" of a deep recursive call, the actual *line* where the error occurs is basically random...

Comment: @Marco13 there is recursion involved in the original program. Link to the git project in the post.

Comment: I suspect then that the SOE is due to too deep recursion in the calling code, and it's just a coincidence that when you run out of stack, you happen to be calling a string splitting implementation.